# listening for programmatic change of view controller in UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need a tabbed application to switch from view controller 2 to view controller 1 (home view controller) and then immediately call a method on view controller 1, without any input from the user.  Using `viewDidLoad` doesn't work, since (as far as I can tell) the home view controller stays loaded the whole time; making it visible doesn't load it again.  I've been trying to use `-(void)tabBarController: didSelectViewController:` but it's not getting called either, I assume because it only works with user-initiated selections, not programmatic selections.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `-(void) viewWillAppear` to do this. Once the view is already loaded, you do whatever you want when it appear! Here it is:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   // You code here to update the view.
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  I just tried this in both view controller 1 and view controller 2, but the methods I put in it aren't getting called.  I'm sure I'm misunderstanding--would you mind being more explicit about how I do this?  Sorry for not getting it.

Comment: I edited my answer above! Check it out and test it! You can also include something like `NSLog("Method being called when viewcontroller 1/2 appear")` to check if this method is being called.